# How can I view what is happening in the lower parts of the EAX register in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am doing some assembly homework and thought the best way to get my head around what is going on is to watch what happens in the registers as the program runs. In Visual Studio You can view the registers but I am doing an operation that only changes things in the lower 8-bits of one of my registers so im not sure what I should be looking at. Can anyone help me out?

Here's the question and the code I'm running:

**What will be the hexadecimal value of the destination operand after each of the following instructions execute in sequence?**

```
TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data var1 SBYTE -4, -2, 3, 1

.code main PROC

    call Clrscr

    mov  al, var1   mov ah, [var1+3]

    exit main ENDP

END main
```

Im pretty sure the answer is -4 after the first statement and 1 after the second statement but I want to see it in the registers.

and the register window i have to look as in VS:
[image]

Comment: You want to move -4 (0xfc) to al? and move 0x01 to ah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ah` and `al` registers are just aliases for the lower two bytes of `eax`, and so you can just monitor the `eax` entry in the register window.  In your example, `ah` is `0x36` and `al` is `0x65`.  You might also need `mov al, [var1]` to get the value at that address, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Ok, so after the first statement my EAX register is: 75C136FC After the second its 75C101FC.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, those are the right values.  The `al` part is the last two hex digits (`FC` in your example).  The `ah` part is the second-to-last pair (`01` in your second example).

Comment: What part of those values are the al and ah registers, just the first 16 bits worth of number?

Comment: @Matt: I updated my comment -- see if the new version answers your questions.

Comment: Hmm, ok cool. I though the answer would be -4 (decimal) after the first statement and 1 after the second statement. FC would be 252 wouldnt it?

Comment: @Matt: `FC` hex is `252` decimal as an unsigned byte, which is `-4` as a signed byte.